Is Microsoft Graph sdk for java thread-safe?
I am using msgraph sdk to get 'User' details in an application. Initialized the GraphServiceClient for app-only authentication as specified in the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java-app-only?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3.
private static Properties _properties;
private static ClientSecretCredential _clientSecretCredential;
private static GraphServiceClient _appClient;

public static void initializeGraphForAppOnlyAuth(Properties properties) throws Exception {
    // Ensure properties isn't null
    if (properties == null) {
        throw new Exception("Properties cannot be null");
    }

    _properties = properties;

    if (_clientSecretCredential == null) {
        final String clientId = _properties.getProperty("app.clientId");
        final String tenantId = _properties.getProperty("app.tenantId");
        final String clientSecret = _properties.getProperty("app.clientSecret");

        _clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();
    }

    if (_appClient == null) {
        _appClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientSecretCredential,
                new String[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
    }
}

I want to query the 'users' using certain filter and select criteria, e.g.
_appClient.users().get(requestConfig -> {
        requestConfig.queryParameters.filter = "displayName startsWith \'A\'";
        requestConfig.queryParameters.select = new String[] { "displayName", "id", "mail" };
        requestConfig.queryParameters.top = 25;
        requestConfig.queryParameters.orderby = new String[] { "displayName" };
    });

However, in my application, this particular request may happen from the context of different threads.
My queries are:

Does each thread need to instantiate GraphServiceClient separately, or, can we initialize once and share across threads?
If the instance (_appClient) can be shared, is it thread-safe to do so or do we need to synchronize access to it?

The following artifact versions are used: microsoft-graph (v 6.20.0) and azure-identity (1.14.1).

Referring this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=java
You can use a single client instance for the lifetime of the application.. It should be thread safe

@samabcde: Thanks for referring the link. However, it doesn't explicitly mention if the client instance is thread-safe. Do I still need to apply synchronization when accessing this single client instance from multiple threads?

@Siddhartha Ghosh — you are right, the answer about client instance lifetime does not answer your question. Your question is correct and essential.
